# How do I interchange the XML attribute position in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have XElements in my XML document and most of it contains two attributes, id and class. I want to interchange the position to class and id. I will explain it better now.

My XML content:

```
<p id="ch2" class="ch-title"><span class="bi">Value 1</span></p>
<p id="h1_2.1" class="h1"><span class="bi">Value 2</span></p>
<p class="noindent1">Value 3</p>
<p class="head"><span class="bi">Value 4</span></p>
```

What I want:

```
<p class="ch-title" id="ch2"><span class="bi">Value 1</span></p>
<p class="h1" id="h1_2.1"><span class="bi">Value 2</span></p>
<p class="noindent1">Value 3</p>
<p class="head"><span class="bi">Value 4</span></p>
```

Comment: Why do you want this? That's HTML, not XML. You can't represent every valid HTML document as XML. `<br>` for example isn't valid in XML. Attribute order isn't significant in either language.

Answer (score 0):

This will put the first attribute last:

```
XElement el = XElement.Parse("<p id='id' class='class' />");
XAttribute firstAttr = el.FirstAttribute;
firstAttr.Remove();
el.SetAttributeValue(firstAttr.Name, firstAttr.Value);
Console.WriteLine(el);     // <p class="class" id="id" />
```